# Windows Form link two radiobuttons to the same method that includes if-else statement (beginner!)

Tags: c#, radio-button

I've just started to work with Windows Form and there's something I can't figure out. I have two radiobuttons on the form that are listed to the same method. The method looks like this, and it is in a class other than the MainForm.cs:

```
public double CalcBMR()
{
double bmr = 0.0;
if (isFemale)
bmr = (10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age) - 161;
else
bmr = (10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age) + 5;
return bmr;
}
```

So, what I want to do is telling the program that rbtnFemale.Checked = isFemale = true, and that rbtnMale.Checked = isFemale = false, but how do I do that considering that the isFemale bool has to be private (and in another class) and that I cannot write one different method for each option?
This is what I've tried but apparently it doesn't work:

```
private void rbtnFemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool isFemale = true;
bmrCalc.CalcBMR();
}
```

Or also this:

```
private void rbtnFemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool isFemale = true;
bmrCalc.CalcBMR(isFemale);
}
```

WHich of course doesn't work because "No overload for method CalcBMR() takes 1 argument". I don't know what to do.
Thank you in advance

Comment: The instance bmrCall should have something that allows you to set the variable _isFemale_ used inside the CalcBMR otherwise, if you cannot modify that method, you are out of luck. Could you add the full code of the class type of _bmrCalc_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what I want to do is telling the program that rbtnFemale.Checked = isFemale = true

Then do so, by substituting this expression for the old `isFemale` variable.

```
public double CalcBMR()
{
    double bmr = 0.0;
    if (rbtnFemale.Checked)
        bmr = (10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age) - 161;
    else
        bmr = (10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age) + 5;
    return bmr;
}
```

If you don't want your `CalcBMR` function to rely on UI elements, have it accept a `bool isFemale` instead.

```
public double CalcBMR(bool isFemale)
{
    double bmr = 0.0;
    if (isFemale)
        bmr = (10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age) - 161;
    else
        bmr = (10 * weight + 6.25 * height - 5 * age) + 5;
    return bmr;
}
```

and call it with the appropiate argument

```
private void rbtnFemale_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bmrCalc.CalcBMR(rtbnFemale.Checked);
}
```

Comment: Given the author's comment of "The method looks like this, and it is in a class other than the MainForm.cs", I think your second method would work best.  +1

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Maximilian, I had never thought of trying that! As Idle_Mind specified, the second method worked best! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You must declare is female variable out of radio button changed method with public keyword.
2. Your calculation method can't accept any parameter.